# Practical PID stability?

Tags: pid-controller

When watching a PID loop lock onto a final output we can often see a variety of waveforms, the most common of which is a sine wave of decreasing amplitude that gradually becomes a straight line.

My questions is this: Do PIDs ever settle to a stability comparable to the noise in the system or is there always some "wobble" around that level?

Comment: I don't think there's a general answer since this depends a lot on the nature of what's being regulated.

Comment: Because of the "differential" D-factor, there should be an increase in noise at high frequencies, although once the loop is closed the noise is "diminished" by feedback. But the "noise" tends to better "stabilize" the response of a system ... I remember that my servomechanism teacher spoke of a "system" where we voluntarily injected a PRBS so that it works better. (?)

Comment: Just curious who thinks this is a useless question that should be downvoted and closed - and why

Comment: Found this ... https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why-is-PID-not-good-for-Noisy-Feedback-systems-while-it-performs-well-for-disturbed-systems and this https://folk.ntnu.no/skoge/prost/proceedings/npcw09/S4-5-Olof-Garpinger-NPCW09.pdf

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained that this is about locating an object with a precision of tens of nanometers, dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will always be a broadband noise input to the loop.

The loop will modify the amplitude of the noise according to the closed loop transfer function.

If the transfer function peaks up at some frequency, then the noise will be enhanced at around those frequencies, which will look like wobble.

> the most common of which is a sine wave of decreasing amplitude that gradually becomes a straight line.

If you see that sort of response, it means your loop is underdamped, so will be peaking up just before it rolls off. This will produce the wobble that you don't want to see.

Adjust your loop transfer function so that it doesn't peak, increase the damping until its response to a step is no longer oscillatory, ideally critically damped but if necessary overdamped, and the then output should be at around the noise level of the various different noise contributions.

This may be more difficult if the loop contains digital elements, which not only add latency which eats into phase margin, but also quantisation noise, which can really mess things up if the changes you want to see are below a quantisation level. It basically means that quantisation noise ceases to behave as uncorrelated noise, and now becomes signal harmonics, including DC. Using sigma delta converters and lots of precision in any computing hardware will mitigate against this.

An engineering colleague of mine used to insist that 'if you can measure it, then you can control to it'. This was in the context of being able to measure -170 dBc phase noise from an RF phase detector, so being able to build a synthesiser that would have that stability between input and output. I don't recall him ever being wrong about that sort of thing.

Comment: At present we are getting 24 useable bits of ADC resolution, so I assume we are controlling to that level, approximately

Comment: https://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/1417-theory-and-practical-considerations-for-measuring-phase-noise-better-than-165-dbc-hz-part-i?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkrmkuPmG9gIVj6Z3Ch11LAGkEAMYASAAEgLsnvD_BwE

Comment: @DirkBruere updated my answer to be more relevant to your question